# TypeError: Member "push" is not available in uint256[] memory outside of storage

Tags: solidity, arrays, alchemy

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract Contract {
    
    function filternEven(uint[] memory arr) external pure returns(uint[] memory a){
          for(uint i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i] % 2 == 0){
                a.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces the following error:

```
TypeError: Member "push" is not available in uint256[] memory outside of storage.
 --> contracts/contract.sol:9:17:
  |
9 |                 a.push(arr[i]);
  |                 ^^^^^^
```

What I want to do is to create pure function without using storage, but seems Solidity pushes me to use it for accessing "push" function of arrays.

What are workarounds here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#arrays)

> Dynamically-sized arrays can only be resized in storage. In memory,
> such arrays can be of arbitrary size but the size cannot be changed
> once an array is allocated.

AFAIK currently there is no good workaround for this issue but to run the loop twice. The first loop is to measure the array length, and the second loop is to fill the array.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answer to this post, the `memory` arrays cannot be resized, so this `push()` cannot work there, as `push()` needs a `dynamically sized array`.

To work around this problem, what you can do is initialize the array indexes rather than push them to the memory array, but yeah, it will not solve your problem completely since you cannot know the array size for sure. Try something like this:

```
for(uint i = 0; I < arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            a[i] =  arr[i];
       }
}
```